# SSL error when I try calling up Google Geocode API

Tags: ruby, google-maps, ssl, google-geocoder

I'm trying to use Ruby to open this URL: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600 Pennsylvania Avenue Northwest, Washington, DC 20500`

It works when I open the URL in my browser: Firefox v36.0.1.

But when I try it in Ruby, I get an error.

My code:

```
require 'open-uri'

baseURL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='
url = baseURL+'1600 Pennsylvania Avenue Northwest, Washington, DC 20500'
p url
p open(URI.encode(url))
```

Response:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `block in connect'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:55:in `timeout'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `connect'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:306:in `open_http'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:776:in `buffer_open'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:203:in `block in open_loop'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `catch'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `open_loop'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:146:in `open_uri'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:678:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:33:in `open'
```

## EDIT

When I add `require "openssl"; OpenSSL.debug=true` after the first line, I get this error:

```
OSSL_DEBUG: IS NOW ON!
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800: warning: error on stack: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `block in connect'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:55:in `timeout'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `connect'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:306:in `open_http'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:776:in `buffer_open'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:203:in `block in open_loop'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `catch'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `open_loop'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:146:in `open_uri'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:678:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:33:in `open'
```

Comment: Since the maps is working as it supposed to be so I think the problem may be on ruby: https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

Answer (score 1):

You might have to update Ruby's SSL certificate.
Get the file "cacert.pem" from a Google search and place it in the folder:

```
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\1.9.1\rubygems\ssl_certs
```

(I tried to guess your Ruby folder from the error you posted)

This is probably what is causing your issue

## EDIT

There is an environment variable that needs to be set as well.
I placed it in my development and production initializers as this:

```
ENV["SSL_CERT_FILE"] = "C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ssl_certs/cacert.pem"
```

This sets the environment variable for Rails only, avoiding having to set it with Windows control panel.